# How to design code without repetitions to catch errors in mvc framework?

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, error-handling, silex

Let's suppose there is model that performs some logic on saving object. This logic consists of db-transactions, some external services calls.

```
class ExampleModel {
  //some field
  //constructor and getters with setters

  public function save() {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->somequery();
    $db->anotherone();
    $object->externalApiCall();
    $object->saveToCache();
  }


}
```

My question is what is the best way to catch errors and make rollbacks?

**Solution#1**
Catch everything in the model, rollback there, log some information and re-throw error to a controller. Will look something like this:

```
class ExampleModel {
  //some field
  //constructor and getters with setters

  public function save() {
    try {
     $db->beginTransaction();
     $db->somequery();
     $db->anotherone();
     $object->externalApiCall();
     $object->saveToCache();
    } catch (DbException $e) {
      $db->rollback();
      $logger->log($e->getMessage());
      throw $e
    }
     catch (ApiExcetpion $e) {
       somelogic();
       throw $e;
     }
  }


}
```

My main concern with this approach is that there is a lot of redundancy in writing try/catch blocks. For every composite method there will be try catch block.

Solution #2
Throw errors in a Model, and handle rollbacks/logging etc in a controller. This one I don't like because it breaks MVC pattern, and a controller becomes fat.

Solution #3
Binding error-listeners to an app instance so that they will handle exceptions according to their logic. Example:

```
class ExampleModel {
  //some field
  //constructor and getters with setters

  public function save() {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->somequery();
    $db->anotherone();
    $object->externalApiCall();
    $object->saveToCache();
  }


}

$app->bind_error_handler("DbTransactionException", function () {
     rollback();
     log();
     return View::render("some error");
});
```

I overall like this approach because there are no numerous try/catch blocks. Controller is skinny and error logic is de-coupled from everything else. My concern with last approach is whether or not it is considered best practice. Also is this approach flexible and will it give me flexibility of a first approach?

**Overall question:**
What is considered best practice in handling errors (transactional and other) in MVC world? And which solution from what I have provided is the best one?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM (like Doctrine) and let the [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) take care of transactions handling.

All the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations are queued until you invoke `YOUR_ORM::flush`. When an exception occurs the transaction is automatically rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have few questions.
1) Is it rollbacked when DBtransaction error occurs? Or I can specify on which exception roll back happens?
2) Is it possible to bind rollback to exceptions from another operations not related to db as I wrote in my example?
3) Is it handled in Doctrine when using just DBAL? Or I need ORM for this?

Comment: With doctrine you can define your transaction boundaries, and specify when you need to roll back or don't. You need an ORM to do this.

Comment: Ye, but then it becomes ordinary beginTransaction/commit/rollback cycle and my question remains about error handling

Comment: Most of the time you don't need to do it. No need to beginTransaction/commit/rollback with an ORM, this is done automatically.

Comment: It is needed in an example that I have provided in a question. ORM controls transactional logic related to database but transactions can contain other tasks.